# Log own hours, must opportunities be tied to events?

Tags: civivolunteer

I've installed CiviVolunteer, and some things aren't clear to me. (And existing questions about them are quite old, and promise things to come.)

1. Can volunteers log their own hours, and must they be logged in to do so?
2. Do volunteer opportunities have to be tied to an event in CiviEvent? Most of our volunteers are regular volunteers, helping in collections, or helping with maintenance tasks at our historic site, not for actual events. Is this possible? How do I set this up?

(We're on Civicrm 5.28.x, running on Wordpress, if it matters. Upgrading is on the to do list.)

Comment: you could consider just using Activities to record the data you need and you can add whatever custom fields you need. then you could use Caldera forms to collect that data. users would not 'need' to be logged in but risks them creating duplicate contact records if they use Dave v David with a different email etc. You could potentially send them an email with checksum link to avoid that. if you do so, you may even be able to avoid using Caldera as i think (could be wrong) that there is an extension or something for Activities via a Profile

Comment: Thanks! I'm making progress setting it up as a Profile. Sort of. 
I'd like to configure Volunteer Locations (we have 4 + places volunteers serve, and it is useful to be able to filter the logs by location), and I can't seem to figure that out. (I want selectable options, not an open text field.)
It also does not seem possible for me to create volunteer projects -- clicking Volunteers > New Project from the menu gets me to a screen with a CiviVolunteer heading, but nothing else (besides the menus).

Comment: have you checked if it adds new Permissions